# PROS + Vex Cortex: No response when requesting system info

Tags: c

Using Purdue Robotics Operating System with a Vex Cortex on OS X. Attempting to flash it with the included uniflash program, but it is throwing an error during the flash process. Here is the logs.

```
CC -I../include -I../src init.c
LN ./bin/auto.o ./bin/init.o ./bin/opcontrol.o ./firmware/libccos.a -lgcc -lm to bin/output.elf
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
  12108       0    3840   15948    3e4c ./bin/output.elf
arm-none-eabi-objcopy ./bin/output.elf -O binary ./bin/output.bin
UniFlash v0.7 by Stephen Carlson
Using serial port /dev/tty.usbmodem1411 (USB Serial)
Stopping user code... done.
Error: No response when requesting system info
Interrogating VEX system...
```

Comment: So what? And how is that related to C?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the output from your shell you are running PROS 1.6 or older which is now out of date as of September. Try upgrading to the latest version found [here](https://github.com/purduesigbots/pros/releases) and see if the problem persists.